# Recommended PSU for a 6 card mining rig?

Tags: graphics-cards, power-supply

As the question suggests...

Some background info first....

I'm looking at building quite a few mining rigs that can mine a wide variety of coins. Each rig is going to have 6 GPUs each, and are going to be made up of 'older' Pascal Cards, like the 1080 and the 1080 Ti.

Each of these cards will be on a PCI-E Riser (duh), and each riser would either have a 6 pin power adapter, or a MOLEX power adapter.

It should be noted that there is no one brand of GTX 1080/Ti that I will be going after, instead, I will be using whatever cards I can get my hands on, so work with virtually all known brands in mind.

Getting to the actual question, I need a PSU that can power the 1080s and their risers comfortably. Any brand of PSU would do just fine, and I'm looking at spending around 400 USD on a single unit. Preferably, I would like to have one PSU per rig, instead of two. But two in one system is always an option.

Thanks for viewing!

Comment: As you live in the US, I can't really suggest one, but I'd say to look at a power supply with at least 1800W for safety purposes. Each 1080ti will pull about 250w from the PSU, so that leaves 300w to play with. And this is bottom of the chain, meaning there will be little headroom available.

Comment: Sites like [PC Part Picker](https://pcpartpicker.com/) are able to directly estimate system wattage from parts (including other parts besides the GPUs). This can help inform you of a good PSU to use.